# How to get Paid User And Free User from google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm New when it comes to google analytics and I have an Apps that use google analytics, but I got some question, Can we use google analytics to track paid and free user separately? If it can where I can find it in google analytics? I'm quite confused with a lot of information in there to use it in data studio

some metrics that I used right now from Google Analytics:
`users` -> to get all unique user that come to my apps

Answer (score 0):

You can distinguish whether sessions that came or not from paid campaigns, but a user can have more than one session and each session could have been started by different channels, for example from a pay channel and another from an organic channel, but the user is always the same. So, with basic tracking, I'd talk about sessions and not users.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can track such details, but you need to let Google Analytics know, who do you consider to be a free or a paid customer, as this is not a standard dimension. This can be achieved with Custom Dimensions.

Key steps involve:

1. Creating the custom dimension in Google Analytics administration. This is a property level setting. Based on your description, this will likely be a user level dimension.
2. You need to adjust your tracking code (or Google Tag Manager settings) to include the customers' level among the data, which is sent to Google Analytics. You need to refer the proper dimension ID, which you get during the creation of it.
3. You need to apply the given custom dimension to your reports. This can be done by using a secondary dimension within the standard reports, or by creating a Custom report. It is also possible by creating a segment of different users, and to apply this segment to various reports.

Further reading is available in this [support article](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en).